# Percentage memory usage of the process in C (or java)

Tags: c, linux, memory

I would like to get the percentage of memory used by a single process using `/proc/pid/` pseudo-filesystem.
With `/proc/pid/status | grep Vm` I get some useful information:

```
VmPeak: Peak virtual memory size.
VmSize: Virtual memory size.
VmLck: Locked memory size.
VmHWM: Peak resident set size.
VmRSS: Resident set size.
VmData: Size of date.
VmStk: stack.
VmExe: text segments.
```

Based on this information, how can I get the percentage of memory used by a single process?

Comment: What is percentage of memory used by a single process?

Comment: Thank you for requesting information! I mean RAM memory for a single process.

Comment: I meant, what memory is count exactly? So where you encounter difficulties? What you've tried?

Comment: I would understand if you can apply a formula, starting from the output of "/proc/pid/status", to get the value (or percentage) of the memory used by the process in question!

Comment: have you try using "htop" command? You must get the pid of the process to see which one is.

Comment: I do not understand what result exactly you want to get. Do sum of all of above divided by RAM size and multiplied by 100 is enough for you?

Comment: @MauroBilotti I do not want to use htop or similar, I would get everything from /proc/pid/*, thanks.

Comment: @Vovanium It may be sufficient, but need summing them all (VmPeak, VmSize, VmLck, VmHWM, VmRSS, VmData, VmStk, VmExe) ?

Comment: Is it sufficient for your needs? (Maybe excluding peak values or using only them)

Comment: To understand my point: there are many caveats on defining 'used memory'. First, some of used process data may by swapped out (do they count or not?). Second, some amount of address space may be allocated, but do not filled with data (same question). Third, some data used by process may be not placed on its address space but accessible through system calls e. g. IO buffers or so (same question). Fourth, when process is cloned some RAM is shared between them (should it count as original's, copy's memory, both, or not count at all?). More questions appear when you dig in...

Comment: ...With all of it it may appear you'll never get exact 100% value when summing all processes memory.

Comment: Considerations is just, but because of what I have to do for the moment the calculation above may be sufficient, even if it is very superficial, but useful...